# How can I ensure that my buttons do not move in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Before I press the equals button on my program, I get this:

[image: Before]

But after, if my answer is smaller than 0 or greater than 9, this happens:

[image: After]

For this same reason I can't use

```
self.button.config(width=x, height=y)
```

Without messing up the entire code. Here's a small peice of my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.a = ''
        self.math1 = 0
        self.math2 = 0

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.c_button = tk.Button(self)
        self.c_button['text'] = 'C'
        self.c_button.command = self.clear_all
        self.c_button.grid(row=6, column=1)

    def clear_all(self):
        self.a = '0'
        self.math1 = 0
        self.math2 = 0
```

Is there any way to stop it from moving the other buttons apart?

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure the grid so that the widget for the result spans multiple columns, using [`columnspan`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/grid.htm#M11).  You have not shown the part of the code which creates the result, but I suspect you need to do something like this:

```
    self.result_button.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4)
```